# How to combine two tables allocating Sold amounts vs Demand without loops/cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

My task is to combine two tables in a specific way. I have a table `Demands` that contains demands of some goods (tovar). Each record has its own ID, Tovar, Date of demand and Amount. And I have another table `Unloads` that contains unloads of tovar. Each record has its own ID, Tovar, Order of unload and Amount. `Demands` and `Unloads` are not corresponding to each other and amounts in demands and unloads are not exactly equal. One demand may be with 10 units and there can be two unloads with 4 and 6 units. And two demands may be with 3 and 5 units and there can be one unload with 11 units.

The task is to get a table which will show how demands are covering by unloads. I have a solution ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/118841/1)) but I think that there is a better one. Can anybody tell me how such tasks are solved?

What I have:

```
------------------------------------------
| DemandNumber | Tovar  | Amount | Order |
|--------------------------------|--------
|  Demand#1    |  Meat  |   2    |   1   |
|  Demand#2    |  Meat  |   3    |   2   |
|  Demand#3    |  Milk  |   6    |   1   |
|  Demand#4    |  Eggs  |   1    |   1   |
|  Demand#5    |  Eggs  |   5    |   2   |
|  Demand#6    |  Eggs  |   3    |   3   |
------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------
|  SaleNumber  | Tovar  | Amount | Order |
|--------------------------------|--------
|  Sale#1      |  Meat  |   6    |   1   |
|  Sale#2      |  Milk  |   2    |   1   |
|  Sale#3      |  Milk  |   1    |   2   |
|  Sale#4      |  Eggs  |   2    |   1   |
|  Sale#5      |  Eggs  |   1    |   2   |
|  Sale#6      |  Eggs  |   4    |   3   |
------------------------------------------
```

What I want to receive

```
-------------------------------------------------
| DemandNumber |  SaleNumber  | Tovar  | Amount |
-------------------------------------------------
|  Demand#1    |  Sale#1      |  Meat  |   2    |
|  Demand#2    |  Sale#1      |  Meat  |   3    |
|  Demand#3    |  Sale#2      |  Milk  |   2    |
|  Demand#3    |  Sale#3      |  Milk  |   1    |
|  Demand#4    |  Sale#4      |  Eggs  |   1    |
|  Demand#5    |  Sale#4      |  Eggs  |   1    |
|  Demand#5    |  Sale#5      |  Eggs  |   1    |
|  Demand#5    |  Sale#6      |  Eggs  |   3    |
|  Demand#6    |  Sale#6      |  Eggs  |   1    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Here is additional explanation from author's comment:

- Demand#1 needs 2 Meat and it can take them from Sale#1.
- Demand#2 needs 3 Meat and can take them from Sale#1.
- Demand#3 needs 6 Milk but there is only 2 Milk in Sale#3 and 1 Milk in Sale#4, so we show only available amounts.
- And so on.

The field `Order` in the example determine the order of calculations. We have to process Demands according to their Order. Demand#1 must be processed before Demand#2. And Sales also must be allocated according to their Order number. We cannot assign eggs from sale if there are sales with eggs with lower order and non-allocated eggs.

---

The only way I can get this is using loops. Is it posible to avoid loops and solve this task only with t-sql?

Comment: What is tovar? Instead of so many words just show us some structure, data and deaired result...

Comment: I put a SQL Fiddle link with table definitions, sample data and my solution of task

Comment: You could do this with a recursive cte if I understand correctly.  I still think an programic or etl based solution is better for this type of work

Comment: Could you explain, row by row, how you calculate the final `Amount` value in your example?

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov Demand#1 needs 2 Meat and it can take them from Sale#1. Demand#2 needs 3 Meat and can take them from Sale#1. Demand#3 needs 6 Milk but there is only 2 Milk in Sale#3 and 1 Milk in Sale#4 so we show only available amounts. And so on.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks. I'll try to use recursive cte.

Comment: @GaaraofDesert, if the `Amount` values are `int` and not too large (not millions), then I'd use a table of numbers to generate as many rows as the value of `Amount`. Then it is easy to join `Demand` with `Sale` and group and sum as needed. I can show you the query tomorrow if you want. Otherwise, a plain straight-forward cursor (in fact, two cursors) would be simple to implement, easy to understand and with `O(n)` complexity. If Amounts are small, set-based variant is likely to be faster than cursor. If Amounts are large, cursor may be faster. You need to measure performance with actual data.

Comment: I'll be grateful to you for showing query. Amounts are int and very small (less than 100).

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, I swear I have found the same solution for int type but didn't posted because of Amount :)

Comment: I edited the title of the question and added your comments into the question. Without these additional explanations it is hard to understand the question.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, have a look at my attempt. Maybe there is a way to avoid expanding rows in SQL Server 2014 - some clever use of running totals, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Amount` values are `int` and not too large (not millions), then I'd use a [table of numbers](http://web.archive.org/web/20141209041043/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html) to generate as many rows as the value of each `Amount`. 
Here is a good [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) describing how to generate it.

Then it is easy to join `Demand` with `Sale` and group and sum as needed.

Otherwise, a plain straight-forward cursor (in fact, two cursors) would be simple to implement, easy to understand and with `O(n)` complexity. If `Amounts` are small, set-based variant is likely to be faster than cursor. If `Amounts` are large, cursor may be faster. You need to measure performance with actual data.

Here is a query that uses a table of numbers. To understand how it works run each query in the CTE separately and examine its output.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/edcf1/1/0)

```
WITH
CTE_Demands
AS
(
    SELECT
        D.DemandNumber
        ,D.Tovar
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.Tovar ORDER BY D.SortOrder, CA_D.Number) AS rn
    FROM
        Demands AS D
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP(D.Amount) Numbers.Number
            FROM Numbers
            ORDER BY Numbers.Number
        ) AS CA_D
)
,CTE_Sales
AS
(
    SELECT
        S.SaleNumber
        ,S.Tovar
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.Tovar ORDER BY S.SortOrder, CA_S.Number) AS rn
    FROM
        Sales AS S
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP(S.Amount) Numbers.Number
            FROM Numbers
            ORDER BY Numbers.Number
        ) AS CA_S
)
SELECT
    CTE_Demands.DemandNumber
    ,CTE_Sales.SaleNumber
    ,CTE_Demands.Tovar
    ,COUNT(*) AS Amount
FROM
    CTE_Demands
    INNER JOIN CTE_Sales ON
        CTE_Sales.Tovar = CTE_Demands.Tovar
        AND CTE_Sales.rn = CTE_Demands.rn
GROUP BY
    CTE_Demands.Tovar
    ,CTE_Demands.DemandNumber
    ,CTE_Sales.SaleNumber
ORDER BY
    CTE_Demands.DemandNumber
    ,CTE_Sales.SaleNumber
;
```

---

Having said all this, usually it is better to perform this kind of processing on the client using procedural programming language. You still have to transmit all rows from `Demands` and `Sales` to the client. So, by joining the tables on the server you don't reduce the amount of bytes that must go over the network. In fact, you increase it, because original row may be split into several rows.

This kind of processing is sequential in nature, not set-based, so it is easy to do with arrays, but tricky in SQL.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was thinking about. Actually I believe that is a one of those rare cases when you just can't avoid cursors. I just can't think of any set based solution and this solution only works with int type of amount field.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what your requirements are or what the business rules are or what the goals are but I can say this -- you are doing it wrong.

This is SQL.  In SQL you do not do loops.  In SQL you work with sets.  Sets are defined by select statements.

If this problem is not resolved with a select statement (maybe with sub-selects) then you probably want to implement this in another way.  (C# program?  Some other ETL system?).

However, I can also say there is probably a way to do this with a single select statement.  However you have not given enough information for me to know what that statement is.  To say you have a working example and that should be enough fails on this site because this site is about answering questions about problems and you don't have a problem you have some code.

Re-phrase the question with inputs, expect outputs, what you have tried and what your question is.  This is covered well in the FAQ.

Or if you have working code you want reviewed, it may be appropriate for the code review site.

Comment: I have updated topic. And I want to know if there is a way to resolve this task without loops in T_SQL only. Thanks for mention code review site, I didn't know there is one.

Comment: The issue is it looks like the requirements require iterative solution -- but you have not said if this is true -- for example could demand #5 have gotten their eggs from sale number 6 and is it required to specify which sale.  With sets this is much easier if the sold eggs are in a "pool" and demand is checked against that.

Comment: I added fields Order in example that determine the order of calculations. We have to process demands according to their Order. Demand#1 must be processed before Demand#2. And sales also must be allocated according to their Order number. We cannot assign eggs from sale if there are sales with eggs with lower order and non-allocated eggs.

Answer (score 0):

I see additional 2 possible ways:
 1. for 'advanced' data processing and calculations you can use cursors. 
 2. you can use SELECT with CASE construction

Comment: 1. I think using cursors is the same as using loops. 2. Can you show me how CASE can help in this solution?